# What are the most prominent use cases for Java in scientific computing?

Tags: java

What are the most prominent use cases for Java in scientific computing?

I've viewed the domain heavily C/C++, Fortran and possibly Python dominant, but what about Java?

Comment: Building GUIs around C++ simulation code is the only thing I've seen. Even that application seems to be going away as more people start building web UIs around their C++.

Comment: But I've seen some scientific Java libraries. But IIRC some source said that the reason they picked Java was that it's easier for people that are worse programs to program compared to C++. But I've not understood further motives for doing these sorts of things in Java. Unless they're through JNIed C/C++.

Comment: There are scientific libraries for every programming language. However, the question specifically asked about "prominent" use cases.

Comment: @user14717 Yes, because since Java is not used that much in game programming or audio etc. then it's likely that it's much less rich than C++ in use cases.

Comment: I have not used Java for scientific computing myself, but compared to the languages you list, there are some safety mechanisms that might make it more suitable for complex programs that have to reliably run for a long time. C++ has some types of runtime errors that don't exist in java, like memory leaks and accessing stale pointers. Java will also catch some other runtime errors in Python at compile time, while pure Python (where you can not use a highly optimized library) will be much slower than Java. The main use case will be if it is the language you're most comfortable with though.